# If $M$ is a martingale, show that $X_t = M_t − kt^2$ is a supermartingale iff $k$ is non-negative.

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

> If $M$ is a martingale, show that $X_t = M_t − kt^2$ is a supermartingale iff $k$ is non-negative.

A supermartingale is defined when $X_s \ge \mathbb E[X_t|\mathcal F_s]$ when $s\le t$. Clearly $X$ must be integrable and adaptable if $M$ is since $kt^2$ is a constant. The main thing then is that we know

$$ M_s = \mathbb E(M_t|\mathcal F_s)$$
I just don't know how to apply this to get a supermartingale for $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $k\geq0$. For $s\leq t$ we (almost surely) have 
$$\mathbb E[X_t|\mathcal F_s] = \mathbb E[M_t-kt^2|\mathcal F_s] = \mathbb E[M_t|\mathcal F_s] -kt^2 = M_s - kt^2 \leq  M_s -ks^2 = X_s,$$ where we have used linearity of conditional expectation, the fact that $(M_t)_t$ is a Martingale and $k\geq0$. Hence, $(X_t)_t$ is a supermartingale.

For the other direction, assume $(X_t)_t$ is a supermartingale. Then, for  $0<s< t$
$$X_s = M_s -ks^2 \geq\mathbb E[X_t|\mathcal F_s] = \mathbb E[M_t-kt^2|\mathcal F_s] = \mathbb E[M_t|\mathcal F_s] -kt^2 =  M_s -kt^2, $$ which implies that $k\geq0$.

Comment: Why does $M_s - kt^2 \Rightarrow k\ge 0?$

Comment: $M_s-ks^2\ge M_t-kt^2$ implies $-ks^2\ge -kt^2$, which implies $k\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t > s$; we compute $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal F_s] = \mathbb{E}[M_t - k t^2 | \mathcal F_s] = M_s - k t^2$.  Since $k \ge 0$, $kt^2 \ge ks^2$ so $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal F_s]  = M_s - k t^2 \le M_s - k s^2 = X_s$.